# mytop to monitor multiple mysql servers

Tags: mysql, performance, monitoring, query-performance

I have multiple MySQL servers running on CentOS. I would like to use mytop to monitor real time database query activities, but do not want to install mytop locally on each of my MySQL instances. How can I install mytop on a network server to monitor multiple MySQL servers (nodes) on the same network just by running a command like the one below for example:

```
mytop -h db-test-1
```

This should display results for database db-test-1, and for db-test-2 or 3, just basically change the db hostname appropriately.

Comment: this seems to be a recognised option - http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/mytop.html - what troubles are you having? The user that connects will need the 'PROCESS' priv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magicly, mytop thought of your question, a decade in advance, and had a `-h` flag. It also supports `-u` for user, `-p` for password, `-P` for port, and other options as per the [mytop pod page](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/mytop.html) in a similar way to mysql.

So you're able use it on a remote host like:

```
mytop -h db-test-1
```